# To show the elements of an object in differrent tables using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsrender

Here is my jsrender html

```
<script id="pageDetails1" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">{{>pageName}}</td>
        <td class="hidden-xs">{{>pageCount}}</td>
    </tr>
</script>
<script id="pageDetails2" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">{{>pageName}}</td>
        <td class="hidden-xs">{{>pageCount}}</td>
    </tr>
</script>
<script id="pageDetails3" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">{{>pageName}}</td>
        <td class="hidden-xs">{{>pageCount}}</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Here is the html table ids,to which im inserting the templates

```
<tbody id="pageDetails-1"></tbody>
<tbody id="pageDetails-2"></tbody>
<tbody id="pageDetails-3"></tbody>
```

Here is the jquery code im using to push an array named "tdaPages" to these ids.

```
$("#pageDetails-1").html($("#pageDetails1").render(tdaPages));
$("#pageDetails-2").html($("#pageDetails2").render(tdaPages));
$("#pageDetails-3").html($("#pageDetails3").render(tdaPages));
```

What i want:
is to get the first 10 elements in pageDetails1 id,then the next 10 in pageDetails2 and then the next 10 elements in pageDetails3.

What i am getting:
It shows the same values for all. That is pageDetails1,pageDetails2,pageDetails3 shows the same elements.

Can anybody suggest how to solve this?

Comment: _an array named "tdaPages"_  yes that would be same for all.

Comment: Use #index to check counter for different pageDetails section

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jsrender.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var tdaPages = [
            { pageName: "One", pageCount: "1"},
            { pageName: "Two", pageCount: "2"},
            { pageName: "Three", pageCount: "3"},
            { pageName: "Four", pageCount: "4"},
            { pageName: "Five", pageCount: "5"},
            { pageName: "Six", pageCount: "6"},
            { pageName: "Seven", pageCount: "7"},
            { pageName: "Eight", pageCount: "8"},
            { pageName: "Nine", pageCount: "9"}
        ];
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="pageDetails-1"></table>
    <table id="pageDetails-2"></table>
    <table id="pageDetails-3"></table>

    <script id="pageDetails1" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {{if #index < 3}}
        <tr>
            <td class="hidden-xs">{{>pageName}}</td>
            <td class="hidden-xs">{{>pageCount}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/if}}
    </script> 
    <script id="pageDetails2" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {{if #index > 2 && #index < 6 }}
        <tr>
            <td class="hidden-xs">{{>pageName}}</td>
            <td class="hidden-xs">{{>pageCount}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/if}}
    </script> 
    <script id="pageDetails3" type="text/x-jsrender">   
    {{if #index > 5 && #index < 9 }}
        <tr>
            <td class="hidden-xs">{{>pageName}}</td>
            <td class="hidden-xs">{{>pageCount}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/if}}
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#pageDetails-1").html($("#pageDetails1").render(tdaPages));
        $("#pageDetails-2").html($("#pageDetails2").render(tdaPages));
        $("#pageDetails-3").html($("#pageDetails3").render(tdaPages));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```